# Storing and shuffling a deck of cards using a vector c++

Tags: c++

Hello all I've been stuck on this problem for the longest time and have been working on it for the past few days for hours at a time. I want to shuffle a deck of 52 cards in a vector similar to the code below but don't know to go about doing it. All help would be appreciated. Hopefully it'll be in the most basic form of code possible as I am taking an introductory level course. (This isn't the full task of my assignment).

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> vi;


    for(int i=1; i <= 10; i++)
      vi.push_back(i);

//before shuffling
    cout <<"Before shuffling: " << endl;;
    for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)//printing index: value
      cout << i << ": " << vi[i] << endl;

random_shuffle(vi.begin(), vi.end());

cout << "\n ------------ \n";

//after 
cout <<"After shuffling: " << endl;
for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
  cout << i << ": " << vi[i] << endl;
}
```

so the code randomizes numbers however I want to randomize deck of cards...

and after figuring out how to do that, I need player 1 to store this as his deck of 7 random cards as a vector, pushing that back to its own vector.

Comment: So, what is `z`? Maybe post an [mcve]?

Comment: You did shuffle the vector. Only problem is `a` and `z`, both undeclared

Comment: oh, a and z is meant to be 1 and 10, sorry let me edit that now.

Comment: It looks like it is shuffeling here:http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fae07fc96e61215c

Comment: How we are supposed to know what happened? We can't get telepathically your error messages, or your crashes.

Comment: So, your problem isn't how to shuffle a vector, but how to fill a vector with all values of a deck's cards.

Comment: How are you _storing_ a deck of cards? I think you should figure that out before you try and shuffle the deck.

Comment: oh yes, @kfsone thats right..

Answer (score 2):

In new code you want to use `std::shuffle`, *not* `std::random_shuffle`.

Using it, shuffling a deck of cards can look something like this:

```
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> cards(52);

    std::iota(cards.begin(), cards.end(), 1);

    std::random_device rnd;
    std::mt19937_64 gen(rnd());

    std::shuffle(cards.begin(), cards.end(), gen);

    std::copy(cards.begin(), cards.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Genuine curiosity: why did you prefer shuffle over random_shuffle?

Comment: @kfsone `random_suffle` is deprecated in the current standard and will be removed in C++17.

Comment: @kfsone: The version of random_shuffle that he's using has a terrible specification. For example, it was originally prohibited from using `rand()` to generate its random numbers, so there's no dependable way to seed its generator (`srand` may or may not work--it shouldn't with a proper implementation of C++98/03, but is allowed to in C++14).

Comment: C++ 14 added another overload of `random_shuffle` that lets you specify what generator it should use, but that's also deprecated, and has its own unique definition of the random number generator that gets used. Bottom line: `random_shuffle` is kind of a mess; `shuffle` is much cleaner.